# Why does ckfinder break image tags when editing?

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I have ckeditor and ckfinder configured properly and when I inserted a picture it works but when I added some styles its prints the styles outside the style tag

Comment: It would be useful if you provide version information. Besides that i would like to confirm that you didn't add any custom plugins and that everything is standard? Try CKEditor.version; in your console for the version of your CKEditor

Comment: Im using version 4.1 and I'm using the standard full version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my issue was the fact that my php installation had magic_quotes enabled so that's what was throwing off my ckeditor.